# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Datefield'

Tags: python, django

In the file models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publishers = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.Datefield()
```

When I run the command

```
$ python manage.py validate
```

I get the error message

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Datefield'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be [`models.DateField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield) with a capital `F`.

So your `Books` model should look like this:

```
class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publishers = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()  # <--- Typo was here
```